# Visual studio: Set default open tab as SolutionExplorer instead Team Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2010

when i open any solution it shows TeamExplorer as default open tab(may be last open tab).but can i make Solution exporer as default open tab for all solutions ?

Comment: I am trying to accomplish the same in Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but I think I figured out how to fix it at least for me.

All I did was change the order the tabs are arranged in.

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

now Solution Explorer comes up by default.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on the Visual Studio shortcut and select Properties.
2. You will see under the Shortcut tab that the Target field will contain text similar to this:

   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"
3. Append the command shown below, and click the Apply button.

   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /Command View.TfsSourceControlExplorer

If your shortcut is on the desktop and pinned to the start menu, you’ll need to apply this change to both shortcuts.  I’ve verified that the above steps work on Visual Studio versions 2008, 2010, 2012, and 2013.